# Why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null" in my script?

Tags: javascript

I am using the imageUploaded.js library and I am getting an error in the chrome dev.
I have pasted a larger snippet of the code below, but the line that is highlighted in chrome for the error is:

```
if ( elem.nodeName === 'img' ) {
```

I understand basic js, but can't follow exactly what's happening in this library, so I'm not sure what this error means or how to fix it.

```
  ImagesLoaded.prototype = new EventEmitter();

  ImagesLoaded.prototype.options = {};

  ImagesLoaded.prototype.getImages = function() {
    this.images = [];

    // filter & find items if we have an item selector
    for ( var i=0, len = this.elements.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      var elem = this.elements[i];
      // filter siblings
      if ( elem.nodeName === 'img' ) {
        this.addImage( elem );
      }
      // find children
      // no non-element nodes, #143
      var nodeType = elem.nodeType;
      if ( !nodeType || !( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) ) {
        continue;
      }
      var childElems = elem.querySelectorAll('img');
      // concat childElems to filterFound array
      for ( var j=0, jLen = childElems.length; j < jLen; j++ ) {
        var img = childElems[j];
        this.addImage( img );
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Put a `console.log(this.elements);` at the top of `ImagesLoaded.prototype.getImages`. Someone adds a `null` to the elements list instead of an actual element.

Comment: This means that the element/node for which you're trying to find the `nodeName` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the element's value is `null`, so it doesn't have `nodeName` property. Without seeing more code, or the library, it's hard to tell what's going on, but you can avoid errors like these by checking first for the value of element itself and then the property:

```
if ( elem && elem.nodeName === 'img' ) {
    ...
}
```

What this code does: if `elem` is falsy (which includes `null`) it will automatically discard the condition as false (that's how logical AND behaves). Otherwise, it will go ahead and check the `nodeName` just like your original code did.

Comment: @Rudie Hold on while I activate my psychic powers... failed. I still don't have a clue what's going in the code that OP didn't post. If you do, feel free to write a more accurate answer.

Comment: How long will that take? You must be busy!

Comment: lol.  I think im going to throw this up on codepen, and repost.  no idea why the value is null.

Comment: Yeah, it looks weird to me as well, like something is unsetting the images. We'll figure it out once you replicate the error on codepen.